# Flex Air Application on Mac for accessibility

Tags: macos, apache-flex, air, accessibility

I'm trying to run my air app on Mac with the accessibility turned on.   It seems like, it only detects the menu bar and the name on top.  Going through any of the input text field or buttons doesn't seem to work.  I'm using the VO+arrow key to go through the elements but it doesn't seem to goto the application's element.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used the accessibility features on Mac much... but the first thing that comes to mind is the compiler option in Flash Builder that lets you "generate an accessible SWF file". That seems to be checked by default, but w/out it screen readers (like JAWS on Windows) won't work. However, [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7da1.html) seems to say that support for screen readers is not enabled by default.

Comment: I'm not sure if air application accessibility actually works with MAC.  I have the voice over on for MAC and the build is already generate an accessible SWF file.  The thing is the voice over run by Apple doesn't seem to detect any of my items in the application.

Comment: Are you using AIR/Flex/Flash-based widgets or an embedded HTML control? The embedded HTML control (and elements within it) are not accessible; but regular AIR controls should be, if compiled with accessibility enabled. If you roll your own UI elements from one of the base control classes, you may have to set some properties on the objects/classes first before they show up. Also; VO can sometimes have quirky navigation; try clicking on an input field with the mouse and tabbing and see if VO tracks that; if it doesn't track keyboard focus, there's something else wrong.